# Как архивировать файлы и папки с сохранением их владельцев и разрешений?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, permissions, archive

Мне нужно собрать файлы в архив таким образом, что бы после распаковывания этого архива запакованные файлы и директории имели таких же владельцев и такие же разрешения как и до архивирования.
Не важно что делать, главное собрать в архив, что-бы потом владельцы и разрешения остались прежними.
Может какой-то shell-скрипт, который будет собирать разрешения в файл, архивировать вместе с файлом разрешений и второй скрипт, который потом будет распаковывать и выставлять по новой разрешения и владельцев взятые из файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> собрать в архив, что-бы потом владельцы и разрешения остались прежними

например, очень часто используемая для архивирования программа *tar* **именно так и делает** — сохраняет и принадлежность файлов, и выставленные биты разрешений (исполнимость/запись/чтение для владельца/группы/остальных).

демонстрация:

```
$ touch user.file            # создадим файл
$ chmod u=rwx,go= user.file  # запретим доступ к файлу всем, кроме владельца
                             # а владельцу установим все три бита: rwx

$ sudo touch root.file       # создадим файл от имени root-а
                             # он будет его владельцем
$ tar -czf a.tgz *.file      # запакуем эти файлы в архив и сожмём его
```

проверяем, что в архиве:

```
$ tar -tvf a.tgz 
-rw-r--r-- root/root         0 2017-06-05 23:22 root.file
-rwx------ user/user         0 2017-06-05 23:21 user.file
```

как видим, всё верно заархивировалось — и принадлежность, и биты доступа.

---

#### но

если распаковать этот архив от имени рядового пользователя, то:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ tar -xf a.tgz -C dir
$ ls -l dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun  5 23:22 root.file
-rwx------ 1 user user 0 Jun  5 23:21 user.file
```

то, как мы видим, биты-то восстановились, а вот принадлежность файлов — нет: оба принадлежат пользователю (который производил разархивацию).

#### чтобы восстановилась и принадлежность файлов

распаковывать архив надо **от имени пользователя root**:

```
$ sudo tar -xf a.tgz -C dir
$ ls -l dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun  5 23:22 root.file
-rwx------ 1 user user 0 Jun  5 23:21 user.file
```

теперь всё «на месте»: и принадлежность, и права доступа.

Comment: Если tar собран без поддержки ACL, то на целевой системе возможна потеря мета-данных.