# Распаковать файлы с сохранением прав

Tags: linux, доступ, permissions, архивация, tar

Есть архив .tar.bz2, в которой находится несколько файлов файловой структуры для ARM, необходимой для сборки.

---

Дальше для распаковки использую: `tar -xjpvf`

---

В распакованных файлах отсутсвуют файлы из каталога dev

и сопровождается **списком** ошибок:

> tar: ./sdk/InitRamFS/minirootfs/dev/ttyS2: **Cannot mknod: Operation not**
>   **permitted**
>
> tar: ./sdk/InitRamFS/minirootfs/dev/ttyS0: **Cannot mknod: Operation not**
>   **permitted**
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> tar: ./sdk/InitRamFS/minirootfs/dev/null: **Cannot mknod: Operation not**
>   **permitted**
>
> tar: ./sdk/InitRamFS/minirootfs/dev/ttyS1: **Cannot mknod: Operation not**
>   **permitted**

---

***Попытки решения***

`sudo` - Не подошёл, т.к. ВСЕ файлы создаются с владельцем ***root***, но для задачи важно чтоб у разных файлов были соответвующие владельцы, как root так и текущий пользователь

Comment: от имени пользователя root — как раз и [сохраняется принадлежность, записанная внутри архива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675735/178576). поэтому суть вопроса абсолютно непонятна. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, нажав [edit].

Comment: Что в данном случае понимается под другой архитектурой?

Comment: сборка файловой системы на ARM

Comment: Архитектура процессора и файловая система - вещи между собой не связанные. Разберитесь, что у вас за файловая система и вообще поддерживает ли она пользователей.

Comment: C sudo правами всё нормально копируется, описал видимо неправильно, 
мне нужно распаковать файлы так чтоб одни сохранились с root правами, а другие буд-то распаковка была без sudo

Comment: @NorBrickface, ты почти наверняка зря это делаешь, но если хочется, то  дык распакуй от root'а и поменяй права на файлы, которые тебе нужны на доступ о обычного пользователя...

Comment: @NorBrickface *sudo* Вам нужен (на самом деле) для того, что бы писать в папку */dev* а вовсе НЕ для сохранения прав. Проблема тут в другом. Если Вы затарили файлы на ARM и там был каталог *abc* принадлежащий пользователю *abc* с UID==1005, то ведь вполне может быть, что на целевой машине нет пользователя с UID==1005, а если и есть, то это вовсе не *abc*.  И какой UID должен выставлять *tar* в таком случае? Честно говоря, я не знаю, как *tar* решает эту проблему. В *nfs* есть система правил для таких ситуаций.

Answer (score 1):

1. Распаковал обычным способом
2. Из потока ошибок, файлам которым нужны были *root* права отдельно распаковал